# Avatar removed from Pivot point

Tags: unity-game-engine, transformation

I was animating an avatar, and was trying various things out, and all of a sudden she was transformed from her pivot point. She also lost the T-pose. I couldn't figure out how to get her back to the original state, removing the animation didn't help. I am going to deleting that avatar and start over, but first I want to learn from this.

I am really looking for a few things here:

- how could that happen? It looks like somehow the state at some point of the animation became the new "ground" state or something.
- is there anyway I could inspect this state, edit it, or failing that, reset it?
- is there something I should read somewhere to understand this better? I found nothing

**Screen shot of displaced avatar:**

[image]

**The top level inspector in the heirarchy:**

[image]

Here is one with the animator controller:

[image]

[image]

## Update:

The key was the suggestion by Fiffe that you need to make sure your flow gets to your exit state. In my case I was neglecting to do that.

Comment: Mecanim I thought. How can I be sure?

Comment: If it uses animator controller it's Mecanim. Can you show the animator controller? Also, are you animating it in Blender or other 3D software?

Comment: Ok, did that I think. There are a few animation-related dialogs/screens.

Comment: I just bought the `Modern People` package and it came with these animation clips.

Comment: If you click PersonIdle-Walk in the animator you'll go to animator controller. Can you please take a screenshot of it (not the hierarchy)?

Comment: Is the avatar and model from the same package?

Comment: They are from the same package, will get that screen shot.

Comment: I just noticed if I remove the animation component from her, and hit the `reset` button in the inspector, she goes back to normal. But she also loses the `hololens` glasses I mounted on her head. The `reset` does not work if I don't remove the animation component.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem - your HumanoidWalk animation isn't exiting anywhere (there's no transition back from it) and it probably isn't set to looping and that's probably what causes this behavior. Check out this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fXirrS_2mM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's few things that might be causing this. You probably wanna play around with animation clip settings - you can find them by selecting animation clip.

[image]

You can read more about it here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimationClip.html

You probably want to turn off Apply Root Motion in your Animator too.
If that doesn't help you should check if you don't have any empty states (without animations) in your animator controller.